# Uncaught Error: Setting authResponse is not supported from Parse/FB

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I'm getting this error when calling `Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn`, seems intermittent.

Comment: This is a known bug which will be fixed soon.  I don't have the link on me, but it's posted on developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 3):

Switch back to v1 of the API:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
        appId      : '...',
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
        version    : 'v1.0'
    });
};
```

and change the sdk to use 'all.js' instead of 'sdk.js':

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```